# Fullcalendar secting span returns one extra datedays

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, fullcalendar

I'm working on a Backbone project where i use Fullcalendar. I used FC v.1 but when I changed to FC v2 the select method returns a span of two days when clicking in a day td.

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next, today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
        ignoreTimezone: false
    },
    select: this.select,// this launch the click select
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    editable: true,

    aspectRatio: 2.5,
    height: 600,
    weekNumbers: true  
})
```

The simplified involved code in select function is:

```
select: function (startDate, endDate, allDay) {
     console.log("Start date:"+ startDate.format());
     console.log("End date:"+ endDate.format());
}
```

So on clicking in one day's `td` it returns

> *Start date:2014-06-26-*
>   *End date:2014-06-27*

What I suppose it will returns is the same start and end date. Have I wrong? 
Any ideas?

Comment: one correction...to what you are referring to is the select callback and NOT the select method...these are two different things

Comment: Thanks  Dimitris Papageorgiou. Important comment. Even I wonder why 'select' returns an extra day.

Comment: one more thing...it seems(I am not sure) that the select method actually calls the select callback...what do you think?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: The select callback is called when the user makes a selection...manually(by dragging).The select callback is also called when the select method is called...if you observe the call stack in the console you will witness that.Did you got it now?

Comment: I understand what you say. But that not answer my question. 
The question was: If I select two dates why the callback get me three dates. On day extra in the end date (month view). I resolve this by subtracting one day from the end parameter. In FC version 1 it worked fine, but now the returned dates are "exclusively" (in moment js format). I do not understand the point because I have now to make an extra calculation. 
  endDate =endDate.subtract('days', 1);
Thanks any way!